# Swiss Franc currency does not display correctly

Tags: asp.net, xslt, currency, aspdotnetstorefront, currency-formatting

I have an ecommerce site built using aspdotnetstorefront.
The locale is set to

> de_DE

and the currency is to Swiss Franc and it displays like this:

```
139,00 (CHF)
```

I have a problem when it gets to the receipt notification where the price looks like this:
(it is wrong it should be **139,00 (CHF)**

> 1.390.000,00

The display specification for the currency is set to:

```
#,###.00
```

My XML package (line affected) looks like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="receipt:FormatCurrencyWithoutCurrencyCode(Price)" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
```

**FormatCurrencyWithoutCurrencyCode:**

```
#region FormatCurrencyWithoutCurrencyCode
    /// <summary>
    /// Format the currency value into it's localized currency pattern
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sCurrencyValue">The currency value</param>
    /// <returns>The formatted currency string</returns>
    public virtual string FormatCurrencyWithoutCurrencyCode(string sCurrencyValue)
    {
        return FormatCurrencyWithoutCurrencyCode(sCurrencyValue, ThisCustomer.CurrencySetting);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Format the currency value into it's localized currency pattern
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sCurrencyValue">The currency value</param>
    /// <param name="sTargetCurrency">The target currency to base on</param>
    /// <returns>The formatted currency string</returns>
    public virtual string FormatCurrencyWithoutCurrencyCode(string sCurrencyValue, string sTargetCurrency)
    {
        InputValidator iv = new InputValidator("FormatCurrencyWithoutCurrencyCode");
        decimal value = iv.ValidateDecimal("CurrencyValue", sCurrencyValue);
        string targetCurrency = iv.ValidateString("TargetCurrency", sTargetCurrency);

        decimal amt = Currency.Convert(value, Localization.GetPrimaryCurrency(), targetCurrency);

        String tmpS = String.Empty;
        // get currency specs for display control:
        String DisplaySpec = Currency.GetDisplaySpec(targetCurrency);
        String DisplayLocaleFormat = Currency.GetDisplayLocaleFormat(targetCurrency);

        if (DisplaySpec.Length != 0 && Currency.NumPublishedCurrencies() > 1)
        {
            tmpS = amt.ToString(DisplaySpec);
        }
        else if (DisplayLocaleFormat.Length != 0)
        {
            CultureInfo formatter = new CultureInfo(DisplayLocaleFormat);

            // for debugging purposes
            if (CommonLogic.QueryStringUSInt("dec") > 0)
            {
                int decimalPlaces = CommonLogic.QueryStringUSInt("dec");
                formatter.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits = decimalPlaces;
            }

            tmpS = amt.ToString("C", formatter);
            if (tmpS.StartsWith("("))
            {
                tmpS = "-" + tmpS.Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            tmpS = Localization.CurrencyStringForDisplayWithoutExchangeRate(amt, false); // use some generic default!
        }

        return tmpS;
    }

    #endregion
```

Comment: try to use the `de_CH` locale

Comment: Thanks but this made no difference what so ever. I will up-vote your comment anyway :)_

Comment: I'm sorry because I've got no more ideas or solutions for your problem. Good luck anyway!

Comment: What's the content of the function `FormatCurrencyWithoutCurrencyCode`? Can you add that to your question? It looks to me that there's some error in there (comma vs dot, or not removing `(CHF)` correctly).

Comment: @Maestro13, I have added this to my question: please can you have a look.

Comment: @sp-1986 Hm that did not clear up the fog - it makes use of other classes not mentioned so no answers can be retrieved from this code snippet alone. One thing is intriguing though: one parameter used is ThisCustomer.CurrencySetting - do you know what the value of that property is?

Comment: In short dont purchase aspdotnetstorefront

Comment: @Maestro13, ended up removing "FormatCurrencyWithoutCurrencyCode" and did (Price DIV 10000) which gave the correct figure. Now i need to check why the email notification doesnt display the price. You would have though that an out the box solution would work out the box.

Comment: @sp-1986 Agree that an out of the box solution should work as one. Don't agree with your change which may cause other problems - better check again why the price was multiplied by 10K in the first place. Wild guess: customer currency setting is JPY?

Comment: @Maestro13, to be honest i am sick and tired of working on this junk. You are right its probably broken something else. I think its because the store is assuming the locale of the SQL server is different to the locale in the store. So it does something funky with the numbers.